# How to convert an array to a string

Tags: php, arrays

What I want is to convert an array to a string so I can display it on my websites. I made a query to select the values `id, title, date, auteur`. When i use my function I made for this, I get the following error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/beheer/index.php on line 444
>   Array.

The function is as following:

```
<?php
include ('connect/connect.php');



function getListContentMain() {
    global $con;
    $dbname = 'content';
    mysqli_select_db($con,$dbname);
    $q = "SELECT * FROM main LIMIT 5";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$q);

    $ListContentMainData = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['id'];
        echo $row['title'];
        echo $row['date'];
        echo $row['auteur'];
    }

    $ListContentMainData[] = $row;

    return $ListContentMainData;
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: What line is 444? Also, `$ListContentMainData[] = $row;` needs to go inside of your loop.

Comment: `I made a query to select the values id, title, date, auteur...` No you didn't. Your query selects every column `*`, you then display your selection using `echo` and return the last `$row` (again, including all columns) wrapped in another array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`implode`](https://www.php.net/implode) it up

```
return implode(' ',$ListContentMainData);
```

You are returning an array but you are trying to print it as a normal string , so in that case you need to `implode` it (array) and convert it to a string.

#### Rewrite like..

```
  $ListContentMainData = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['id'];
        echo $row['title'];
        echo $row['date'];
        echo $row['auteur'];
        $ListContentMainData[]=$row['id'];
        $ListContentMainData[]=$row['title'];
        $ListContentMainData[]=$row['date'];
        $ListContentMainData[]=$row['auteur'];
    }

    return implode(' ',$ListContentMainData);
```

Comment: implode will not work on a multi-dimensional arrays. $ListContentMainData array contains $row, which is an array. You will receive Notice: Array to string conversion

Answer (score 1):

This will make an array of strings, one for each row in the table with columns separated by a space (you could change that in the implode statement).

```
function getListContentMain() {
    global $con;
    $dbname = 'content';
    mysqli_select_db($con,$dbname);
    $q = "SELECT * FROM main LIMIT 5";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$q);

    $ListContentMainData = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['id'];
        echo $row['title'];
        echo $row['date'];
        echo $row['auteur'];
        array_push($ListContentMainData, implode(' ', $row));
    }
    return $ListContentMainData;
}
```